# How much is undone by “Ignore your last roll on the Youth Path table” in Lifepaths Step 4?

Tags: character-creation, eclipse-phase

On page 59 of *Transhuman*, of the many background events we have:

> You fall in with the wrong crowd. Ignore your last roll on the Youth Path table and take the Street Rat package (p. 21) for the same amount of PP as you rolled. Proceed to Step 5.

How much does this undo? Does your morph get undone? Your next path? Just your package from that roll?

Comment: Split rest into new question

Comment: [Related] [How do you reconcile conflicting Transhuman Lifepath results in Step 3?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/65072)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only whatever happens in the *last roll* is ignored but not before that. Since you roll 1 to 3 times on said table, it could mean that you get no Youth Path. If you rolled three times, only roll three is ignored leaving one and two intact.