# How do you reconcile conflicting Transhuman Lifepath results in Step 3?

Tags: character-creation, eclipse-phase

In the *Transhuman* method of character creation, Step 3 can be rolled multiple times if you get the split or fractured childhoods. What does that mean for your morphs? Do you just default to the last one applicable? What happens if you roll something completely non-sensical, like Split childhood : Earth-born, Created not made?

I really like the options for different means of char-gen, but these steps are less than clear sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get multiple morph, you have multiple morphs! That is not a problem: you just lucked out! Remember, morphs are equipment that can be lost, upgraded, and swapped. They are items, nothing more, nothing less.

These options, as all "life paths", are there to introduce a small element of randomness in character creation.  I view them as a aid to enhance whatever background I came up with.  Or, given some rolls, to create an interesting background.  I view them as seeds to build on, not as hard and fast rules. Therefore, if something does not quiet fit (which is really easy with randomness) and you either cannot figure out a way to make it fit or hate it, then discard it.

Comment: True... just in this case I'm making a tool to do it so have to settle on more rigid rules... Hmm. Although the same applies I suppose. Will decide on an interpretation and stick with it.

Comment: Tool as in piece of software?  I so, store your results in a list (or vector or array) and if you get to this edge case, remove the last entry from the list/vector/array.